# Global low level mouse hook causes freeze when clicking on title bar buttons

Tags: c++, windows, internet-explorer, windows-7, hook

I'm writing an add-on for IE. I need to close a modal dialog on external click.

So far, I've used WM_NCACTIVATE to receive those notification but it seems that on Windows 7 (IE8) I don't get this message (I'm running on low integrity and I've verified it with spy++; it seems that it does work when I run on high integrity - weird stuff).

I've tried to use the regular mouse hook for the DeskBand UI Thread. I do get all the mouse events except the ones from outside the dialog.

So I've turned to using the global low level mouse hook (WH_MOUSE_LL). 
it all works fine but from some very odd reason I get a 5-10 second freeze when i click on any one of the title bar buttons.

After some online research I've realized it's a common problem but I found no solution. Some of the people said it's performance issues but even if my hook function only calls to "CallNextHook" it still happens.

Any ideas on how to fix it or alternative ideas to close a modal dialog on external click?

Comment: I think it is a singularly *horrible idea* to even try to override such a basic bit of standard Windows behavior such as the very idea of what a Modal window is. I also suspect that's why you are finding it so difficult to do. This question only makes me wonder why someone would want to do this, and the answers I can come up with don't smell very good.

Comment: I agree; the whole point of modal dialogs is to be modal.  If you don't want a modal dialog, do make the dialog modal.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by removing the WH_MOUSE_LL.
This works fine in Windows XP, but freezes the ENTIRE COMPUTER, and sometimes until I SWITCH THE COMPUTER ON AND OFF.

I think it's ridiculous they haven't fixed this bug.
It has wasted a lot of my time.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well in a low level mouse hook, when opening a context menu could cause the system to freeze for a second or two.

It was a priority inversion problem. Try raising the thread's priority from which you install the hook by calling [SetThreadPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686277).

Comment: Downvoters, please provide reasoning. (e.g. You don't think it's a priority inversion problem or you have a better solution)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't see any evidence to suggest that this is a priority inversion.  Messing with priorities without a clear understanding of the underlying problem (e.g., proof that there is a priority inversion) seems reckless.

Comment: It's hard to prove, but my only explanation. Fact is: No mouse hook, works fine. Mouse hook: hangs occasionally. Mouse hook in high priority thread: works fine. I can reproduce it every time. If anyone has a better explanation, I'd be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

**Educated guess**:  I suspect that since you're an IE add-on, you're running in a low-integrity process (which is how IE's Protected Mode works).  Low-integrity processes cannot, by default, send window messages to medium- or high-integrity processes.  The title bar is probably part of the IE frame, which is likely a medium-integrity process.  In your hook processing, perhaps you're causing an extra message to be sent.  For example, since it's a click outside your dialog, you might be sending a message to close the dialog.  The integrity mechanism blocks the message because you're crossing a low-integrity/medium-integrity boundary.  After five seconds, the system determines that the app has become unresponsive, which manages to get the original click message unstuck.

In other words:  setting a low-level hook from a low-integrity process is almost certainly a bad idea.

(Global hooks in general are usually a bad idea, in general, as they impose a cost on all UI processes in the system.  Other programs shouldn't have to pay a tax for your program to behave correctly.)

Modal dialogs in Windows have OK/Cancel/Dismiss command buttons.  Yours shouldn't be an exception.  To have a dialog dismiss by clicking away is contrary to the design model, so you're likely to have trouble implementing this and even if you managed a fragile hack, it will likely confuse and annoy your users.

Other elements in Windows, like pop-up or drop-down menus, accomplish the close-on-click-away by capturing the mouse (see [SetCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646262%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), which allows the menu code to see when the mouse does something outside the window.  But that's going to be very difficult to do for a dialog since a dialog has child controls that also need to interact with the mouse.  Capturing the mouse will prevent the children from getting the messages they need.

You need to revisit the close-on-click-away decision with whoever designed the feature.  Any attempt to implement it will be a fragile hack and likely confuse users.